# Pgfplots: embedding a line in a surface

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to draw an identity across a surface plot. This identity should start at the bottom left, and end at the top right (from tip to tip). With the axis I've given (see below), the v_1=2(v_2-20). This becomes y=2(x-20) given the way the axes are defined. I've tried plotting this in various ways, but it does not seem to work on top of the 3d surface.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\begin{axis}[
    title={secret research}, 
    xlabel=$v_2$, ylabel=$v_1$,
    small,
    x dir=reverse
]
\addplot3[
    surf,
    domain=0:20,
    domain y=0:10,
] 
    {((y^2/(0.5*(x+y))/20)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand the question. Could you please make more explicit what you mean? What does "This becomes y=2(x-20) given the way the axes are defined. " mean? Do you just want to plot `(x,{2*(x-20)})`? But this is a 3d plot.

Comment: @marmot Sorry for it being unclear. I would like to plot the identity that maps across the surface diagonally from v_2=20 to v_1=10. This would be a single function, not a surface, as it is defined at one particular intersection of the v_2 and v_1 axes.

Comment: You want a one-dimensional plot, i.e a line, then? At which z-value should this line be? Should it really be `v_1=2(v_2-20)`, i.e. at `v_1=0` `v_2` will be -40, ie. far off from the surface?

Comment: @marmot Yes one-dimensional, at the z-value of the surface.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope I guess correctly.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,declare function={f(\x,\y)=((\y*\y/(0.5*(\x+\y))/20);}]
\begin{axis}[
    title={secret research}, 
    xlabel=$v_2$, ylabel=$v_1$,
    small,
    x dir=reverse
]
\addplot3[
    surf,
    domain=0:20,
    domain y=0:10,
] 
    {(f(x,y)};
\addplot3[mesh,domain=0:10,point meta=0] ({2*x},{x}, {(f(2*x,x)});
\addplot3[mesh,domain=0:10,point meta=0.5] ({2*(10-x)},{x}, {(f(2*(10-x),x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can choose whatever color you like for those lines.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,declare function={f(\x,\y)=((\y*\y/(0.5*(\x+\y))/20);}]
\begin{axis}[
    title={secret research}, 
    xlabel=$v_2$, ylabel=$v_1$,
    small,
    x dir=reverse
]
\addplot3[
    surf,
    domain=0:20,
    domain y=0:10,
] 
    {(f(x,y)};
\addplot3[mesh,domain=0:10,color=red] ({2*x},{x}, {(f(2*x,x)});
\addplot3[mesh,domain=0:10,color=black] ({2*(10-x)},{x}, {(f(2*(10-x),x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but from the left-most point at (v_1=0,v_2=20,z=0) to the rightmost (v_1=10,v_2=0, z \approx 1). Will change it myself :)

Comment: @pafnuti I add that one. There is one potential piftfall: you need to use mesh since otherwise there will be a closed cycle.

Comment: Does this mean I can't choose an arbitrary colour for the line? Because of the point meta colour map?

Comment: @pafnuti You can choose whatever color you like, I added an update.