How to draw cool 19th-century-style 3d plots?
I like making 3d parametric plots in tikzpicture, e.g. the one below.
My question: is it possible to, instead of decorating the plot with a colour, decorate it with a pattern supported by tikzpicture for 2d drawing, e.g. the northeast lines pattern on the left here:


Example plot:

and the relevant code snippet, generating the red part:
\addplot3[
    surf,
    shader=flat,
    samples=20,    
    domain=50+180:360+180,
    y domain=-1:1,
    z buffer=sort]
    ({0.5 * cos(x)}, {y}, {0.5 * sin(x) + 0.8* sin(90 * (y-1))^2});


I'm happy if this is not possible but there are variant solutions that achieve something similar. The motivation for my question is to draw something at least 10% as good as

i.e. using hatch patterns, level lines, or some other similar artistic technique to decorate my plots.

I don't know of any "pattern fill" but if you just want lines, you can accentuate the mesh lines with \addplot3[ surf, draw=black, ... ] ... ;. The second example you showed seems to have some contours and other (maybe "equipotential" or similar) lines drawn on deliberate paths. There are contour methods (see pgfplots doc) or you can draw specific lines on a surface like here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/616094/how-to-draw-a-path-in-a-surface-with-tikz-pgf or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/450999/pgfplots-embedding-a-line-in-a-surface

If that's your aim you want lines as @tsj suggested. A pattern couldn't follow the contours like that. (At least, not the kinds of patterns PGF has.) What does this have to do with the 19th century? Do you have evidence for the mythical 1873 pgfplots pre-alpha?

@cfr the OP wants to produce figures that look like they were hand-drawn in the 19th century - although the example here is from the early 20th century (see for example https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2014/12/15/jahnke-and-emde-revisited/).

@Marijn Exactly! Although sadly the above is in MATLAB, not in tex.

Bounty started to find an answer beyond the above comment

\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings, patterns, patterns.meta}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\pgfplotsset{view={280}{-10}, axis lines=none}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=interior, line join=round] 
\begin{axis}[name=interior]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=flat,
colormap={transparent!100}{color=(transparent!100) color=(transparent!100)},
mesh/interior colormap={transparent!0}{color=(transparent!0) color=(transparent!0)},
domain=-130:180, samples=20,    
y domain=-1:1, samples y=20,
z buffer=sort,
]({0.5*cos(x)}, {y}, {0.5*sin(x)+0.8*sin(90*(y-1))^2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{tikzfadingfrompicture}[name=exterior, line join=round] 
\begin{axis}[name=exterior]
\addplot3[
surf, shader=flat,
colormap={transparent!0}{color=(transparent!0) color=(transparent!0)},
mesh/interior colormap={transparent!100}{color=(transparent!100) color=(transparent!100)},
domain=-130:180, samples=20,    
y domain=-1:1, samples y=20,
z buffer=sort,
]({0.5*cos(x)}, {y}, {0.5*sin(x)+0.8*sin(90*(y-1))^2});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzfadingfrompicture}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\fill[pattern=dots,             path fading=interior, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(interior)}] (interior.south west) rectangle (interior.north east);
\fill[pattern=north east lines, path fading=exterior, fit fading=false, fading transform={shift=(exterior)}] (exterior.south west) rectangle (exterior.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Edit: From comments - torus with finer spacing:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis equal, axis lines=none,
]
\addplot3[
surf, white, faceted color=black,
domain=0:360, samples=20,
y domain=0:360, samples y=300,
z buffer=sort,
] ({(2+cos(x))*cos(y+90)}, {(2+cos(x))*sin(y+90))}, {sin(x)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}




Could you explain what you're doing? It's unclear to me whether this method can be deformed to make the pattern "wrap around" the 3d shape.

I made this specifically to fill "the red part" with your desired patterns. - I do not understand what you mean by "wrap around". Please edit your question to include compilable code and show an example of what you try to achieve.

I can't include such code, that's ~the content of my question, but I can try to explain. What you drew above takes the 3d shape, projects it into the 2d page and then fills in that area with a pattern, whereas I was asking for whether it's possible to, if you have a map from a square to 3d space, first fill in that square with a pattern, then map it to 3d space. So if we applied this to the grid pattern and 3d shape the torus, we'd get something like this https://i.sstatic.net/7POdM.png with finer spacing. Thanks for your existing answer though! Did that answer your question?

To do something like that, you only need a mapping from a square to your surface and your pattern described by a function. Then it would be simple but intensive to do a multitude of plots. The result would not be unique - many different mappings could be chosen. You could ask a new question about that - this question is all over the place. Always supply compilable code. If you are interested in a specific surface, give compilable code for that surface or choose an example.

I feel like we're speaking at cross-purposes. About uniqueness - a parametrised 3d surface picks out a unique map from a square to R^3. Thanks for the edit. However, your edit only works in the special case of the grid pattern, which was already covered by Marijn's comments above - I am specifically asking for how to do it for arbitrary patterns like northeast lines. I think a new question would get deleted for being too similar to this one. About compilability - thanks for the heads up, I didn't realise and will try to in the future!
